# Partial data in $_FILES variable

Tags: php, apache, file-upload

We have an admin screen where the user could edit a big amount of data and in addition has a few dozen inputs of type file.

In PHP every file input is injected into a superglobal variable called `$_FILES`.

In my local development environment, everything works perfectly,
The problem is that in staging the data we get is partial.

If I save the same data in staging and local, I get only in local the full data what resolves with that when a user tries to upload an image I don't even see it in the `$_FILES` variable.

So my question is, What is the limitation causing this problem in staging?

I have more or less the same php.ini settings (max_post_size, max_upload_size etc..) and I do not have permissions to edit the settings in staging.

#### Specs in staging

- Server version: Apache/2.2.15
- PHP 5.3.29
- Akamai CDN

### Edit

The `$_FILES` output for `Jon Stirling`'s request:
I've encoded it to JSON so it will be more readable.

Staging output:

```html
{
  "user_guide": {
    "name": "",
    "type": "",
    "tmp_name": "",
    "error": 4,
    "size": 0
  },
  "instructionsData": {
    "name": {
      "102": {
        "icon": "",
        "icon_inverted": "",
        "instructionData": {
          "1395": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1398": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1401": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1404": {
            "image": ""
          }
        }
      },
      "103": {
        "icon": "",
        "icon_inverted": "",
        "instructionData": {
          "1405": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1408": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1411": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1414": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1417": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1420": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1423": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1426": {
            "image": ""
          }
        }
      },
      "105": {
        "icon": "",
        "icon_inverted": "",
        "instructionData": {
          "1428": {
            "image": ""
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "type": {
      "102": {
        "icon": "",
        "icon_inverted": "",
        "instructionData": {
          "1395": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1398": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1401": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1404": {
            "image": ""
          }
        }
      },
      "103": {
        "icon": "",
        "icon_inverted": "",
        "instructionData": {
          "1405": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1408": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1411": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1414": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1417": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1420": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1423": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1426": {
            "image": ""
          }
        }
      },
      "105": {
        "icon": "",
        "icon_inverted": "",
        "instructionData": {
          "1428": {
            "image": ""
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "tmp_name": {
      "102": {
        "icon": "",
        "icon_inverted": "",
        "instructionData": {
          "1395": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1398": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1401": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1404": {
            "image": ""
          }
        }
      },
      "103": {
        "icon": "",
        "icon_inverted": "",
        "instructionData": {
          "1405": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1408": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1411": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1414": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1417": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1420": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1423": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1426": {
            "image": ""
          }
        }
      },
      "105": {
        "icon": "",
        "icon_inverted": "",
        "instructionData": {
          "1428": {
            "image": ""
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "error": {
      "102": {
        "icon": 4,
        "icon_inverted": 4,
        "instructionData": {
          "1395": {
            "image": 4
          },
          "1398": {
            "image": 4
          },
          "1401": {
            "image": 4
          },
          "1404": {
            "image": 4
          }
        }
      },
      "103": {
        "icon": 4,
        "icon_inverted": 4,
        "instructionData": {
          "1405": {
            "image": 4
          },
          "1408": {
            "image": 4
          },
          "1411": {
            "image": 4
          },
          "1414": {
            "image": 4
          },
          "1417": {
            "image": 4
          },
          "1420": {
            "image": 4
          },
          "1423": {
            "image": 4
          },
          "1426": {
            "image": 4
          }
        }
      },
      "105": {
        "icon": 4,
        "icon_inverted": 4,
        "instructionData": {
          "1428": {
            "image": 4
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "size": {
      "102": {
        "icon": 0,
        "icon_inverted": 0,
        "instructionData": {
          "1395": {
            "image": 0
          },
          "1398": {
            "image": 0
          },
          "1401": {
            "image": 0
          },
          "1404": {
            "image": 0
          }
        }
      },
      "103": {
        "icon": 0,
        "icon_inverted": 0,
        "instructionData": {
          "1405": {
            "image": 0
          },
          "1408": {
            "image": 0
          },
          "1411": {
            "image": 0
          },
          "1414": {
            "image": 0
          },
          "1417": {
            "image": 0
          },
          "1420": {
            "image": 0
          },
          "1423": {
            "image": 0
          },
          "1426": {
            "image": 0
          }
        }
      },
      "105": {
        "icon": 0,
        "icon_inverted": 0,
        "instructionData": {
          "1428": {
            "image": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Local output:

```html
{
  "user_guide": {
    "name": "",
    "type": "",
    "tmp_name": "",
    "error": 4,
    "size": 0
  },
  "instructionsData": {
    "name": {
      "102": {
        "icon": "",
        "icon_inverted": "",
        "instructionData": {
          "1395": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1398": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1401": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1404": {
            "image": ""
          }
        }
      },
      "103": {
        "icon": "",
        "icon_inverted": "",
        "instructionData": {
          "1405": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1408": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1411": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1414": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1417": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1420": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1423": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1426": {
            "image": ""
          }
        }
      },
      "105": {
        "icon": "",
        "icon_inverted": "",
        "instructionData": {
          "1428": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1431": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1434": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1437": {
            "image": ""
          }
        }
      },
      "106": {
        "icon": "",
        "icon_inverted": "",
        "instructionData": {
          "1438": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1441": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1444": {
            "image": ""
          }
        }
      },
      "109": {
        "icon": "",
        "icon_inverted": "",
        "instructionData": {
          "1447": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1450": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1453": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1456": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1459": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1462": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1465": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1468": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1471": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1474": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1477": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1480": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1483": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1486": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1489": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1492": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1495": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1498": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1501": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1504": {
            "image": ""
          },
          "1507": {
            "image": ""
          }
        }
      },
      ....
```

Comment: Not sure what "partial data in $_FILES" looks like. Can you show us?

Comment: "PHP 5.3.29" — [It's been four and a half years since PHP 5.3 got a security update](http://php.net/eol.php). Stop using it! Use something that is actually supported.

Comment: @JonStirling I've added an example

Comment: @Quentin I agree, it isn't my choice, I work for a big customer and I'm tring for a long time to get him to upgrade

Comment: That's not $_FILES output. Do you check `error` key in `$_FILES`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered there was a module in the Staging that is called `suhosin`, apparently it has more security limits and restrictions.

To find the problem I've added to `php.ini`:

```
suhosin.simulation = 1
suhosin.log.file = 511
suhosin.log.file.name = /tmp/suhosin-alert.log
```

That led me to the error `ALERT-SIMULATION - configured fileupload limit exceeded - file dropped`, after research I had to update these properties in `php.ini`:

```
max_file_uploads = 300
suhosin.upload.max_uploads=300
```

And then all the data appeared correctly